# How to allow download of DOM object to a file

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have a web page (Django-python-jquery website) that contains a `<p>` tag to which I uploaded text from a server side database (according to client's choices).

I want to allow the customer to right the page and download the text (i.e. save locally as a txt file)
Looking all over for this the only way I found will be to save the text as a file on the server and return to the browser a link to the newly created file) and thus download it.

Since the data is already on the client, surely there is a way to save it locally, can someone point me as to how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a jsPDF client side script which would allow you to save in pdf format. worth a try

http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Please have the view source of the above file and 
You could probably change doc.save function from pdf to txt

var initDownloadPDF = function() {

```
$('.download-pdf').click(function(){
                eval(editor.getValue());

                var file = demos[$('#template').val()];
                if (file === undefined) {
                    file = 'demo';
                }
                doc.save(file + '.txt');
            });
            return false;
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to download it as a txt file for various reasons so Still need a way to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after taking a long while to try and do it from the Client I realised the best way will be (as I feared) to have the server create a file with the info needed and point the client (via an ajax call to download it
the Django view (that creates the file upon client hitting the download) looks like:

```
def download_log(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.GET:
        FS_STATIC_DIR = "/root/Documents/pdsc/static/"
        URL_STATIC_DIR = "/static/"
        TEMP_DIR = "tmp/"
        TEMP_FILE_DIR = FS_STATIC_DIR+TEMP_DIR
        heartbeat_content = Heartbeats.objects.get(id=(request.GET['heartbeat_id'])).attachment
        heartbeat_filename = Heartbeats.objects.get(id=(request.GET['heartbeat_id'])).attachment_name
        heartbeat_filename = re.sub('^/','', heartbeat_filename)  # Delete all preceding /
        heartbeat_filename = re.sub('/','-', heartbeat_filename)  # Change all / to -
        try:
            heartbeat_content = base64.b64decode(heartbeat_content)
        except:
            pass

        full_temp_log_file_path = TEMP_FILE_DIR+heartbeat_filename+str(datetime.now())
        full_temp_log_file_path = re.sub(r"\s+", '-', full_temp_log_file_path)
        temp_log_file = open(full_temp_log_file_path, 'w')

        temp_log_file.write(heartbeat_content)
        temp_log_file.close()

        temp_log_file_url = re.sub(FS_STATIC_DIR, URL_STATIC_DIR, full_temp_log_file_path)
        response = HttpResponse(temp_log_file_url, content_type='text/plain')
    else:
        response = HttpResponse("No log requested", content_type='text/plain')

    return response

The relevant ajax code look like:
var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");
                $("body").on("contextmenu", "#heartbeats-table tr", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $rowClicked = $(this);
                    $contextMenu.css({
                        display: "block",
                        left: e.pageX,
                        top: e.pageY
                    });
                    $contextMenu.data("heartbeat-id", $rowClicked.data("heartbeat-id"));
                    return false;
                });
                $(document).click(function () {
                    $contextMenu.hide();
                    $contextMenu.data("heatbeat-id","")
                });
                $("#download_log").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                       'url': '/download_log',
                       'type': 'GET',
                        data: {heartbeat_id:$contextMenu.data("heartbeat-id")},
                        'complete': function( data ){
                            window.location.replace( data.responseText );
                        }
                    });
                });
```